# Delete Method Outlook Item

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm new in Posh and trying to understand this error message when I add `select object`:

> Method call failed because [Selected.System.__ComObject] does not
> contain a method named "Delete".

Here's my code which works fine without the `| select-object`:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject “Outlook.Application”
$MAPI = $Outlook.getnamespace(“mapi”)
$folder = $MAPI.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$SubFolder = $folder.Items | Where-Object {$_.tasksubject -like “*Alert*”} | Select-Object TaskSubject
Foreach ($Folder in $SubFolder)
{
$SubFolder.delete()}
```

Can someone tell me why and where should I place it please? Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

> my code which works fine without the `| select-object` :

Indeed, the **[`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call is your problem**: It returns `[pscustomobject]` instances (which don't have a `.Delete()` method), whereas **you need to act directly on the original Outlook folder items**.

Since it doesn't look like the `Select-Object` call does anything useful in your case, you can simply omit it, and use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) in the same pipeline to call the `.Delete()` method on each folder item (using [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax)):

```bash
$folder.Items | 
  Where-Object TaskSubject -like *Alert* |
  ForEach-Object Delete
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, i use | select... to check visually in ISE if i have one or more items with the same subject, is there another "normal" way of doing this ? Btw, Simplified Syntax is awesome THX !

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Pax212. To see the subject, you could replace the `ForEach-Object` call with `ForEach-Object { $_. TaskSubject; $_.Delete()  }`. If you have further questions, please create a new question post.